# Docker "Ports are not available" error (even though Docker ps doesn't show any containers on that port)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to run a docker container like this:

```
docker run -d --net foodtrucks-net -p 5000:5000 --name foodtrucks-web  myname/foodtrucks-web
```

But for some reason I'm getting the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 0.0.0.0:5000 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5000: bind: address already in use.
```

When I run `docker ps` I only see one container running on a different port:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                  COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                            NAMES
fb527839d40f   docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.2   "/tini -- /usr/local…"   14 minutes ago   Up 14 minutes   0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9300->9300/tcp   es
```

Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Something is listening on port 5000.

Answer (score 0):

You have a process already running on port 5000 (might be not a docker container but something else), try to change port. You can see all processes running with netstat

```
netstat -a -b
```

Or you can check which process is using port 5000 with this command

```
netstat -na | find "5000"
```